# Someone broke in and stole my MacBook and iPod Touch. Now what?

Tags: laptop, macbook, anti-theft

So, somebody has my MacBook (non-pro aluminum, 2009) and iPod Touch (g1). I didn't set the login requirement for any reason (it would only prompt for a password if you install something, like an update) so I'm mildly upset about that (see plus side), and it's running Skype with a stored login. My iPod doesn't have a pin (that was really super annoying, I did that for a few weeks and gave up).

On the plus side this indicates the MacBook won't *need* to get wiped to get used, so maybe those vacation photos and half finished iPhone App/Game are still out there.

So here's my thoughts:
I didn't install logMeIn though I was going to.  I also didn't back it up.
I wish I'd actually installed DynDNS on it instead of my PC.
Skype doesn't start up automatically but it will log in if started.
There's an ssh key on there but all the hosts that have it in authorized_keys no longer do.
The iPod is synced with my PC, but Apple doesn't handle it as it would a stolen iPhone (lock access, and put a message up on the screen).
I want to deauthorize my iTunes account.
I want to send a skype message with a link to something tempting that will silently install something like [adeona](http://adeona.cs.washington.edu/). But silent installs aren't nicely provided (I know why too) and most installs would need to get my `sudo` password entered. Plus it's unlikely to work.

So any ideas, other than being better prepared next time (that would be a different question)? Can you enable the whole .mac thing with "Back to my Mac" with a serial number and without local access (a bit scary)? Doesn't Apple have something they could do besides see if anyone will bring it into an Apple store for installing/wiping (has happened; like tracking iTunes store use, or something)?

PS other items include a Wii and 5-8 games (I didn't even play some yet), a bunch of wrapped Christmas presents I can't ID yet, a PSP, a video camera, a digital camera, an old PSP, a $5 web cam, a $2 microphone, and a backpack to keep it all in.

Comment: @dlamblin, sorry for the rough holiday season.  A little off topic, but try to consider identity theft contingencies as well.

Comment: @hyperslug; yes thanks. It turns out my health insurance provider lost a drive full of client statements in image form 3 months prior. They claim that's low-risk. But they signed me up for a year of credit monitoring; Also I changed all my passwords and revoked my authorized_keys. I did have a tax document pdf though... that sucks.

Comment: Might be a little late, but if you have gmail you can check the IP history.  It's possible they could accidentally have loaded up your account.  It only show recent history, but perhaps Google logs it for longer.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for your loss.
Since you did not mention it, have you reported the burglary? Maybe the police has tools/info in how to trace the goods.

In the mean time, you can add the computer's serial number to stolen Mac databases [here](http://www.mark-up.com/stolen/report-apple-stolen.htm) and [here](http://www.powermax.com/stolen/report).

While it does not help you any further in this case, [LoJack](http://www.absolute.com/products/lojackforlaptops/features) is reported to be effective in recovering stolen laptops.

Comment: Oh, yes I did. I made a report and listed serial numbers. I don't think the mac version of LoJack gets put into the Bios, making it less effective. The fee also seems high given the time limit, I know myself, and I know that I would normally let it expire before something actually happens again.